# How to share any link and or text in facebook from android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

I have tried to share some text and some link to facebook from my android app using facebook SDK.
But problem is that it doesn't allow to share text without appending any link to the text.
Another problem is that i have to login each time during sharing.

Again i am clearing what i actually want is that,
I want to share  anything(may b text,link etc) from my app using facebook default app .

Comment: Can you explain this *from my app using facebook default app*

Comment: For example i want to share some text from my app.Whenever i click share button on my app then the facebook app which was installed before in my device will open . @Jibran Khan

Comment: You have to use Facebook SDK for android. You can get started here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android and http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: It will require login every time i want to share.

Comment: No, FB SDK manages the session itself so not required to login every time until user logs out

Comment: I dont want to show any "Post to wall" option to edit and post  to user. The user will just login then some text will be auto posted to the user profie @JibranKhan

Comment: comments to this question will answer your requirements. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156615/android-posting-to-facebook-without-users-interaction

Comment: Without user confirmation, you cannot post anything to timeline. It will count as a spam and is not possible though

Comment: I am confirming user by login .